# Faild to decode JSON, SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I can’t seem to decode my JSON. It locates, and loads, but fails to decode.

Here is the JSON example:

```
[{
"name": "Hartsfield Jackson Atlanta Intl",
"city": "Atlanta",
"country": "United States",
"iata_code": "ATL",
"_geoloc": {
  "lat": 33.636719,
  "lng": -84.428067
},
"links_count": 1826,
"objectID": "3682"}]
```

Here is my Struct:

```
struct Airports: Codable, Identifiable {
struct GeoLoc: Codable {
    let lat: Double
    let lng: Double
}
var id = UUID()
let name: String
let city: String
let country: String
let iata_code: String
let _geoloc: GeoLoc
let links_count: Int
let objectID: String }
```

Bundle etension:

```
extension Bundle {
func decode<T: Codable>(_ file: String) -> T {
    guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
        fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle.")
    }
    
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
        fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle.")
    }
    
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "y-MM-dd"
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
    
    guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
        fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle.")
    }
    
    return loaded
}}
```

And I call it in my content View like this:

```
let airports: [Airports] = Bundle.main.decode("airports.json")
```

I get the fatalError("Failed to decode (file) from bundle.")
So my question is, what is wrong here? Is the mistake in my Airport Struct?
I know the bundle extension is working, I have used the same with many other JSONS.

Comment: change `try?` to `try`, use a `do catch` and `print(error)` in the `catch`. you will get a much better description there.

Comment: For some reason i found now that the “var id = UUID()” was the cause of the issue… not really sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is beacuse of property of `id` in your structure your json has no key `id` and `id` in structure is not `optional`. You have to change it with

```
let id : UUID?
```

instead of

```
var id = UUID()
```